# how can I manage changes on odoo

Tags: odoo

I am new to odoo, and I would like to know how to manage changes on model and view.

This kind of material is saved in database so that git does not know the changes.

Is there any way to manage changes so that I can put the changes from development to production?

Comment: Hello, if your are going to change models and view from debug mode, then you cannot track that but you can use modify from code for traceking change

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to apply the changes you perform in the XML source files to your existing database, you must perform an upgrade in the according modules.

For example, if you change a view in the module `mail`, you must upgrade the module `mail`.

You can do so by either:

- Re-launching your server, using the `-u` parameter (e.g. `-u mail`)
- In the web interface, go to Apps > The module (e.g. `Discuss`), hit the [`upgrade` button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/244j6.png).

The same logic applies if you perform changes in the stored models fields, if you add or alter some.

Notice that if the records you change in the XML files are surrounded by a `<data noupdate="1">`, this mean that these records are not updated on upgrades. If this is your case, you have to update the records manually. This is the case for email templates for example, so changes done by the users in databases in production are not overwritten by the default email template content.

Comment: I am using developer mode to make my changes. I would like to know if there is any way that I can use git to keep it?

Comment: Well, you can [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the Odoo repository, and push your changes in your own branches.